# How to find accuracy of a model in CNN?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I want to find the accuracy of a customised CNN model. I have weights(w), loss value(l) and test data(x_test) with the class variable(y_test). The weights can't be adjusted, they should remain the same. It will be like a single layer feedforward neural network.

I want to complete this function to give the same accuracy as in Keras.

**Edit 1:** Binary class classification problem.

```
  def accuracy(x_test,y_test,w,l):
     y_pred=numpy.dot(x_test,w)
     acc=...
     return acc
```

How to complete the accuracy statement as they do in Keras or any other API?.

Comment: You want to find the test accuracy, right? You could create a test data set and just test on those, and compare them to the correct output. Then just get the average accuracy.

Comment: Since it will be binary classification problem, I won't be reaching the absolute value. Then how to compare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something similar to [keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py#L24), you just care about `y_test` and `y_pred` (`y_test` is `y_true`):

```
def acc(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.equal(np.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)).mean()
```

This is my POC:

```
import numpy as np

# y_test onehot encoded
y_test = np.array([[1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0],[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]])
y_pred = np.random.random((5,3))

print("y_true: " + str(np.argmax(y_test, axis=-1)))
print("y_pred: " + str(np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)))

def acc(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.equal(np.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)).mean()

print("accuracy: " + str(acc(y_test, y_pred)))
```

Result:

```
y_real: [0 1 2 1 0]
y_pred: [1 1 0 1 0]
accuracy: 0.6
```

**Update 1:** Since it is for binary classification the function will be this:

```
def acc(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.equal(y_true, np.round(y_pred)).mean()
```

POC:

```
import numpy as np

y_test = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
y_pred = np.random.random((5))

print("y_true: " + str(y_test))
print("y_pred: " + str(np.round(y_pred).astype(int)))

def acc(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.equal(y_true, np.round(y_pred)).mean()

print("accuracy: " + str(acc(y_test, y_pred)))
```

Comment: What will be the role of loss value here?

Comment: You don't need the loss to find the accuracy.

Comment: If your values are between 0 and 1, use `np.round()`, otherwise apply a sigmoid function before the `np.round()`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you can pass your `actual` and `predicted` values to `scoring` function available inside `mlxtend` library.

Look [Scoring - mlxtend](https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/evaluate/scoring/) for more explanation.